# How to generate a new PySpark DataFrame by comparing entries in two others?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to search through a Pyspark `DataFrame` containing string fields and determine which keyword strings appear in each. Say I have the following `DataFrame` of keywords:

```
+-----------+----------+
|       city|     state|
+-----------+----------+
|    Seattle|Washington|
|Los Angeles|California|
+-----------+----------+
```

which I would like to search for in this `DataFrame`:

```
+----------------------------------------+------+
|body                                    |source|
+----------------------------------------+------+
|Seattle is in Washington.               |a     |
|Los Angeles is in California            |b     |
|Banana is a fruit                       |c     |
|Seattle is not in New Hampshire         |d     |
|California is home to Los Angeles       |e     |
|Seattle, California is not a real place.|f     |
+----------------------------------------+------+
```

I want to create a new `DataFrame` that identifies which keywords of which type appear in each source. So the desired end result would be:

```
+-----------+------+-----+
|name       |source|type |
+-----------+------+-----+
|Seattle    |a     |city |
|Washington |a     |state|
|Los Angeles|b     |city |
|California |b     |state|
|Seattle    |d     |city |
|Los Angeles|e     |city |
|California |e     |state|
|Seattle    |f     |city |
|California |f     |state|
+-----------+------+-----+
```

How can I obtain this result? I could use `join` to isolate the `body` strings that contain these keywords, but I'm not sure how to track which specific keyword was a match and use that information to create new columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's create and modify the dataframes:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
keywords_df = sc.parallelize([["Seattle", "Washington"], ["Los Angeles", "California"]])\
    .toDF(["city", "state"])
keywords_df = keywords_df\
    .withColumn("struct", psf.explode(psf.array(
        psf.struct(psf.col("city").alias("word"), psf.lit("city").alias("type")), 
        psf.struct(psf.col("state").alias("word"), psf.lit("state").alias("type"))
    )))\
    .select("struct.*")
keywords_df.show()

    +-----------+-----+
    |       word| type|
    +-----------+-----+
    |    Seattle| city|
    | Washington|state|
    |Los Angeles| city|
    | California|state|
    +-----------+-----+
```

If your key words didn't contain spaces you could have `split` your sentences into words, that you'd have `exploded` to get just one word on each line. Then you'd have been able to `join` with your keywords dataframe. It's not the case here because of `Los Angeles`.

```py
text_df = sc.parallelize([["Seattle is in Washington.", "a"],["Los Angeles is in California", "b"],
                          ["Banana is a fruit", "c"],["Seattle is not in New Hampshire", "d"],
                          ["California is home to Los Angeles", "e"],["Seattle, California is not a real place.", "f"]])\
    .toDF(["body", "source"])
```

Instead we'll use a join with a string `contains` condition instead:

```py
res = text_df.join(keywords_df, text_df.body.contains(keywords_df.word)).drop("body")
res.show()

    +------+-----------+-----+
    |source|       word| type|
    +------+-----------+-----+
    |     a|    Seattle| city|
    |     a| Washington|state|
    |     b|Los Angeles| city|
    |     b| California|state|
    |     d|    Seattle| city|
    |     f|    Seattle| city|
    |     e|Los Angeles| city|
    |     e| California|state|
    |     f| California|state|
    +------+-----------+-----+
```